# ¿Como eliminar un elemento en un arreglo en JAVA?

Tags: java, array

Tengo un código de un arreglo de empleados el cuál contiene cédula, nombres y apellidos, necesito realizar un método que me permita ingresar un empleado y que este lo busque y así mismo lo elimine del arreglo.
Después de esta operación queda el espacio donde estaba ese empleado, entonces también necesito correr una posición el resto de empleados.

Comment: Hola Harold , es importante agregues el código que estes realizando, nuevamente te sugerimos revisar [ask] y modifiques tu pregunta,  te invitamos a realizar el [tour] para que conozcas el funcionamiento del sitio, saludos.

Answer (score 1):

una vez creamos un array es de un solo tamaño lo creas de un tamaño de 5 y ese sera su tamaño no puedes "eliminar" un elemento.
Yo te recomiendo usar el Objeto ArrayList que esta en el paquete  de java.utils

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MyClass {
public static void main(String[] args) {
ArrayList<String> cars = new ArrayList<String>();
cars.add("Volvo");
cars.add("BMW");
cars.add("Ford");
cars.add("Mazda");
System.out.println(cars);
//Para acceder a un elemento en el ArrayList, use el get()
cars.get(0);
//cambiar el valor de una posicion
cars.set(0, "Opel");
//eliminar un elemento
cars.remove(0);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Coleccion{
 private Empleado[] empleados;
 private int size;
 public Coleccion(int cant){
  empleados = new Empleado[cant];
  size=0;
 }

 public boolean alta(Empleado emp){

   boolean aRetornar= false;
   if(size<empleados.length-1){
     empleados[size++]= emp;
     aRetornar=true;
   }
  //retorna falso si el arreglo esta lleno
  return aRetornar;

 } 
 public boolean baja(Empleado emp){
   boolean corte= false;
   for(int i=0; i<size&&!corte;i++){
     if(empleados[i].equals(emp)){
       empleados[i]=null; 
       arrastrar[i];
       corte=true;
       size--;
      }
   }
   //retorna falso si no esta el elemento a borrar
   return corte;
 } 
 private void arrastrar(int i){
   while(i<size-1){
     contenedor[i]=contenedor[i+1]; 
   }
 }
 public boolean estaEmpleado(Empleado emp){
   boolean corte=false;
   for(int i=0;i<size&&!corte;i++){
      corte = contenedor[i].equals(emp);
   }
   //devuelve verdadero si el empleado existe
    return corte;
 }
 //este metodo le das una cedula y te devuelve un empleado;
 public Empleado buscarPorCedula(String cedula){
   boolean corte=false;
   Empleado emp = null;
   for(int i=0;i<size&&!corte;i++){
      if(contenedor[i].getCedula().equals(cedula);
         emp= contenedor[i];
   }
  //devuelve empleado si esta y si no devuelve null
  return emp;
 }
}

//ahora la clase empleado
public class Empleado{
  private String nombre;
  private String apellido;
  private String cedula;
  public Empleado(String nombre,String apellido,String cedula){
   this.nombre= nombre;
   this.apellido=apellido;
   this.cedula = cedula;
  }
  //getters y setters; ejemplo
  public String getCedula(){
    return cedula;
  }
  public void setNombre(String nombre){
   this.nombre=nombre;
  }
  public boolean equals(Empleado emp){
   return nombre.equals(emp.getNombre())&&apellido.equals(emp.getApellido())
          &&cedula.equals(emp.getCedula());
  }

}
```

Comment: Hola, gracias por tu contribución, ayudanos a responder preguntas que sean basadas en lo que indica el [help]. Recuerda revisar [answer] para mejorar tus respuestas, saludos.